# How can I make it display what I need after the condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
start_bot=input("Enter '/start' to start the bot: ") 
while start_bot!=("/start"): 
  print (input("Enter start!")) 
  if start_bot==("/start"): 
    print("Welcome!")
```

If you run and type "/start" it will display "welcome". If you run and type "/non-start" it will display "Enter start", then I will type "/start" and run and it will display "Enter start" again. What's the problem?

Comment: You could make this as simple as `while input("Enter '/start' to start the bot: ") != "/start": pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to set the last conditional statement out of the loop, and reassign the `start_bot` variable inside it:

```
start_bot=input("Enter '/start' to start the bot: ") 
while start_bot!=("/start"): 
  start_bot=input("Enter start!")
print("Welcome!")
```

> Output:

```
Enter '/start' to start the bot: /no
Enter start!/start
Welcome!
```